# Laravel 4 refreshes twice on initial loading

Tags: php, laravel

The problem that I am facing is when I initially load the website new.dev.savatours.com, it refreshes twice. Namely it is clearly visible, that it outputs some content, and then suddenly it clears everything and than outputs the content again. Searching through out the requests in the Chrome development console I can not find what is the problem, nor I can detect any problem in my code.

The version of Laravel is 4.2.

Since I can not load the entire code structure, I might hope for any intuitive answer to this question.

Thank you

Comment: afaik the php debug bar is causing this.. you shouldn't activate it on production.. just deactivate it and see if happens again

Comment: Hey, Matei! Thanks! It seems much much better when the debug is turned off. Yet there is again slight flash of content, but still it is much better than it was.

Comment: The slight flash might be caused by too big images.. try to minimze their sizes..